# When passing data between view controllers can't figure out why this parameter is null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm passing an object from a sliding MenuViewController, the source, to a HomeViewController, the destination.

On my MenuViewController, the user enters an airport code, selects it, and the home view controller does some work on it. ***My problem is that the object reaches the HomeViewController as null*** and I can't figure out why.

I start w/ a subclass of NSObject FPLAirport with NSString property airportID.

In my MenuViewController I add table view cells via a modal segue using my AddAirportViewController.

When the user taps on the populated table view cell in MenuViewController the MenuViewController (source) passes the string, airportID, to homeViewController (destination) and I call a method there to do some work.

My airportID object is arriving null and I can't sort out why.

Here is the pertinent code:

First, in my AddAirportViewController.m, prepareForSegue method:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.doneButton) return;
    if (self.airportTextField.text.length > 0) {
        self.airport = [[FPLAirport alloc] init];
        self.airport.airportID = self.airportTextField.text;
    }
```

Next, my MenuTableViewController.m's prepareForSegue and unwind methods:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvcs = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        SWRevealViewController* rvc = self.revealViewController;

        rvcs.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc)
        {
            UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dvc];
            [rvc pushFrontViewController:nc animated:YES];
        };
    }

    //pass the selected airport to the home view controller

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sw_selectedAirport"]) {
        FPLHomeTableViewController *homeViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        homeViewController.airportID = [self.airportsArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
}

-(IBAction)unwindToMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    FPLAddAirportViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    FPLAirport *addedAirport = source.airport;
    if (addedAirport != nil) {
        [self.airportsArray addObject:addedAirport];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

My HomeTableViewController.m viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.revealButtonItem setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.revealButtonItem setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    [self configureView];
    [self initializeWeatherData];
}
```

And initializeWeatherData methods:

```
-(void) initializeWeatherData {

        //test for an existing airport ID in airportsArray

    NSLog(@"self.airportID is %@", self.airportID);

    if (self.airportID != nil) {

        FPLWeatherData *weatherData = [[FPLWeatherData alloc] init];

        //        [weatherData downloadHomeFieldObservation];
        [weatherData downloadWeatherObservationWithID:self.airportID];

        self.airportNameLabel.text = weatherData.observationAirport;
        self.timeAgoLabel.text = weatherData.timeSinceObservation;
        self.windLabel.text = weatherData.windObservation;
        self.altimeterLabel.text = weatherData.altimeterObservation;
        self.visibilityLabel.text = weatherData.visibilityObservation;

    }
```

Finally, the pertinent part of FPLWeatherData class, subclass of NSDictionary:

```
@implementation FPLWeatherData

-(void)downloadWeatherObservationWithID:(NSString *)airportID {

    //call the API
    //airport location hard-coded

    NSURL *weatherURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/APIKeyGoesHere/geolookup/astronomy/conditions/q/%@.json", airportID]];
    NSData *weatherData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:weatherURL];
    NSError *error  = nil;
    NSDictionary *weatherDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:weatherData options:0 error:&error];

    //observation Airport;
    self.observationAirport = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"station_id"];

    //wind observation
    NSString *windDirection = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"wind_degrees"];

    //    NSString *windIsNorth = @"0"; fix this!!

    //    if ([windDirection isEqualToString:windIsNorth]) {
    //        windDirection = @"360";
    //    }

    NSString *windSpeed =[[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"wind_mph"]; //convert to knots
    self.windObservation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ / %@", windDirection, windSpeed];

    //visibility, altimeter, condition

    self.visibilityObservation = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"visibility_mi"];
    self.altimeterObservation = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"pressure_in"];
    self.weatherCondition = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"weather"];

    //time since observation - cache this date formatter later

    NSString *observationTime = [[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"] valueForKey:@"observation_time_rfc822"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
    NSDate *timeNow = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *timeObserved = [dateFormatter dateFromString:observationTime];
    int observationDifference = [timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:timeObserved] / 60;
    self.timeSinceObservation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i minutes ago", observationDifference];


    //compose sunset time from API

    NSString *sunsetHour = [[[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"sun_phase"] valueForKey:@"sunset"] valueForKey:@"hour"];
    int sunsetHourInt = [sunsetHour intValue];

    NSString *sunsetMinute = [[[weatherDictionary valueForKey:@"sun_phase"] valueForKey:@"sunset"] valueForKey:@"minute"];
    int sunsetMinuteInt = [sunsetMinute intValue];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [components setHour:sunsetHourInt];
    [components setMinute:sunsetMinuteInt];

    NSDate *sunsetTime = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
    int sunsetDifference = [sunsetTime timeIntervalSinceDate:timeNow] / 60;

    if (sunsetDifference <= 0) {
        self.isNight = YES;
    } else {
        self.isNight = NO;
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem is in the unwind segue in my MenuViewController, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Usually its better to post the code along with your question, the relevant part of course

Comment: More likely than not, you aren't grabbing the VC from `segue.destinationViewController` in your `prepareForSegue` method. If you're instantiating a new instance of `HomeViewController` then you're passing the info to the wrong object.

Comment: Corrected issues with original post. Sorry for wasting the community's time with a useless question, as originally posed. I hope this is better.

Comment: It's axiomatic that parameters passed between view controllers are nil.  About 60% of the time this is due to setting the value in a different object instance from the one you subsequently try to fetch it from.  And 30% of the time it's due to setting/fetching a value when the object where it's being stashed is not actually there -- a nil pointer.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, thanks! I'm trying to find the place in my code that I'm doing it and fix it!

Comment: LyricalPanda, Hot Licks thanks for your input. I corrected the problem - it wasn't what you suggested but your answers led me in the direction I needed to find the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested answers to this question led me in a direction I hadn't considered.

It turns out that it wasn't a instantiation issue or what Hot Licks suggested.

I was attempting to access a object directly and not the string property of the object. This is what I did to correct the problem: In MenuTableViewController.m's prepareForSegue method I changed the code from this:

```
 //pass the selected airport to the home view controller

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sw_selectedAirport"]) {
        FPLHomeTableViewController *homeViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        homeViewController.airportID = [self.airportsArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
```

to this:

```
//pass the selected airport to the home view controller

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sw_selectedAirport"]) {

    NSLog(@"the airports array is, %@", self.airportsArray);

    FPLHomeTableViewController *homeViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    FPLAirport *selectedAirport = [self.airportsArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];

    homeViewController.airportID = selectedAirport.airportID;
}
```

Thanks for the answers, I wouldn't have found the problem without the suggestions that led me in a different direction.